# Calcular subtotal e total com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, matemática

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para a quantidade de items na linha tabela seja multiplicado pelo valor unitário da mesma linha formando um sub-total para ser totalizado no final.
No meu código, até então só consegui calcular o valor total apenas somando sem passar pelas unidades a serem multiplicadas pelo valor unitário.

```js
var atualizaCarrinho = function(){
    var carrinhos = $('.carrinho');
    carrinhos.each(function(){
        var carrinhoAtual = $(this);
        var valorItem = carrinhoAtual.find('.item-total:visible');
        var valorTotal = carrinhoAtual.find('.valorTotal');
        var qtdTotal = carrinhoAtual.find('.qtdProdutos');
        var resultado = 0;

        valorItem.each(function(){
            var tdAtual = $(this);
            var pegaValor = parseFloat(tdAtual.text());
            resultado = parseFloat(resultado + pegaValor);
        });

        valorTotal.text(resultado);
        qtdTotal.text(valorItem.length);
    });
};
atualizaCarrinho();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carrinho">
  <h2>Carrinho entrega em Santa Catarina</h2>
  <table border=1>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td>Quantidade</td>
     <td>Valor Unitário</td>
     <td>SubTotal</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Tablet miPad 18</td>
     <td class="qtd_item">6</td>
     <td>499.0</td>
     <td class="item-total">499.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Tablet miPad 19</td>
     <td class="qtd_item">1</td>
     <td>599.0</td>
     <td class="item-total">599.0</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div><strong>Valor total: </strong> R$ <span class="valorTotal">0</span></div>
  <div><strong>Quantidade de Produtos: </strong> <span class="qtdProdutos">0</span></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim?

```js
var atualizaCarrinho = function(){
    var carrinhos = $('.carrinho');
    carrinhos.each(function(){
        var carrinhoAtual = $(this);
        var valorItem = carrinhoAtual.find('.item-total:visible');
        var valorTotal = carrinhoAtual.find('.valorTotal');
        var qtdTotal = carrinhoAtual.find('.qtdProdutos');
        var item_total = $('.item-total');
        var qtdItems = $('.qtd_item');
        var vt= 0;
        var resultado = 0.0;
        for(var i = 0; i < qtdItems.length; i++){
            var qtdItem = parseFloat(qtdItems[i].innerHTML);
            var vtItem = qtdItem * parseFloat(item_total[i].innerHTML);
            item_total[i].innerHTML = vtItem;
            resultado += vtItem;
            vt += qtdItem ;
        }   
                
        valorTotal.text(resultado);
        qtdTotal.text(vt);
    });
};
atualizaCarrinho();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carrinho">
  <h2>Carrinho entrega em Santa Catarina</h2>
  <table border=1>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td>Quantidade</td>
     <td>Valor Unitário</td>
     <td>SubTotal</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Tablet miPad 18</td>
     <td class="qtd_item">6</td>
     <td>499.0</td>
     <td class="item-total">499.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Tablet miPad 19</td>
     <td class="qtd_item">1</td>
     <td>599.0</td>
     <td class="item-total">599.0</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div><strong>Valor total: </strong> R$ <span class="valorTotal">0</span></div>
  <div><strong>Quantidade de Produtos: </strong> <span class="qtdProdutos">0</span></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, tinha tentando utilizar o for, porém dava erro. Mas agora entendi a lógica.

Comment: Usar classes para identificar os td's e os elementos não é muito bom, deve usar id's. Ainda bem que ajudou, coloque a resposta como aceite.